# Nextjs13 fetch data for client component at build time

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I have a sanity Nextjs13 project and in Nextjs12 I used the use `getStaticPaths()` and `getStaticProps()` for my dynamic pages, now Should I just fetch my data on a server component in a lib directory that does it during build time and then have it available on demand for my client component?

Comment: Can't do it at build time any longer. Another useful thing that was removed when Nextjs "upgraded" from 12 to 13.